# Pygame and Livewires button press not working?

Tags: python, pygame, livewires

so in my menu in a game I'm creating a picture is displayed which shows how to play the game, and I have some code so that when the player presses the b button it returns to the main menu, but this doesn't work, can someone help me please?

```
def manual():

    image = games.load_image("options.jpg")
    games.screen.background = image
    if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_b):
        menu()
    games.screen.mainloop()
```

the 'menu()' is another function which has all the main menu code in it

Here is the menu function

```
def menu():
    pygame.init()
    menubg = games.load_image("menubg.jpg", transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = menubg

    # Just a few static variables
    red   = 255,  0,  0
    green =   0,255,  0
    blue  =   0,  0,255

    size = width, height = 640,480
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    games.screen.background = menubg
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(500,30)

    choose = dm.dumbmenu(screen, [
                            'Start Game',
                            'Manual',
                            'Show Highscore',
                            'Quit Game'], 220,150,None,32,1.4,green,red)
    if choose == 0:
        main()
    elif choose == 1:
        manual()
    elif choose == 2:
        print("yay")
    elif choose == 3:
        print ("You choose Quit Game.")
```

Comment: what does the menu function do? have you tried debugging your code?
You also wrote - return to main menu, does that mean, that manual function is called from main menu?

Comment: the manual function is called from the menu function at one point yes

Comment: in menu() you call manual() which call menu() with call manual() etc. - it is bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `is_pressed()` in `manual()` doesn't wait for your press so you call `mainloop()` so I think you never leave that loop.

I see other bad ideas in your code like:

- `menu()` call `manual()` which call `menu()` which call `manual()` etc. - use `return` and use loop in `menu()`
- every time you call `menu()` you call `pygame.init()` and `pygame.display.set_mode()` - you should use it only once.

**EDIT:**

I don't know how `games.keyboard.is_pressed()` works (because there is no that function in PyGame) but I think `manual()` could be:

```
def manual():

    image = games.load_image("options.jpg")
    games.screen.background = image

    while not games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_b):
        pass # do nothing

    # if `B` was pressed so now function will return to menu()
```

and you have to create loop in menu:

```
running = True

while running:
    choose = dm.dumbmenu(screen, [
                        'Start Game',
                        'Manual',
                        'Show Highscore',
                        'Quit Game'], 220,150,None,32,1.4,green,red)
    if choose == 0:
        main()
    elif choose == 1:
        manual()
        # if 'B' was press manual() will return to this place
    elif choose == 2:
        print("yay")
    elif choose == 3:
        running = False
        print ("You choose Quit Game.")
```

Comment: So how would I be able to make the manual function stay on the screen? Thanks for helping me clean up the code as well :)

Comment: I add some sugestions to answer.